How can I close the select file dialog with testcafe
I have a test where I upload files. I am using the setFilesToUpload functionality of testcafe and it is working. However I have to click a button on the package to load the input field. But, this triggers the open file dialog of the browser. Does anyone now how to close it again with testcafe. The test is still running fine I just have a unnecessary open file dialog in front of the browser. Thanks.
I want to close the select file dialog.
[Open File Dialog Window[1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3K7EOMql.jpg

The file selection dialog is a part of the user’s operating system. TestCafe cannot interact with the operating system’s UI. Therefore, if you want to upload files during your test, you must use a different strategy.
Refer to the following help topic to read more about this: Upload Files with TestCafe
